# How can I convert CSV data to JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I wrote the code that gets data from a device.
The form of the data is **csv**. Below is the data value.

```
1,1.635946,1.636609,1.640240,1.636091

2,1.642825,1.640267,1.639013,1.636568

3,1.636835,1.636022,1.637664,1.637144

4,1.641332,1.641166,1.637950,1.640760

5,1.636041,1.637437,1.640702,1.633678
```

But I want the data in **json** format. So I tried using an [online converter](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm) and got the following values:

```
[

 {

   "1": 2,

   "1.635946": 1.642825,

   "1.636609": 1.640267,

   "1.640240": 1.639013,

   "1.636091": 1.636568

 },

 {

   "1": 3,

   "1.635946": 1.636835,

   "1.636609": 1.636022,

   "1.640240": 1.637664,

   "1.636091": 1.637144

 }

]
```

What parts of my code should I modify if I want to get these values?

Below is my code.

```
var Timer;
var i = 0 ;
    setTimeout(function(){
        Timer = setInterval(function(){

            port.write(meascommand+'\n');
            i++;

            if(i==5){
                clearInterval(Timer);
            }
        },5000);
    },1000);

port.on('data',function(devicevalue){
    arrayvalue = devicevalue.toString();
    eachvalue = arrayvalue.split(';');
var results = [];

            var index = i ; 
            var ch0value = eachvalue[0] ; 
            var ch1value = eachvalue[1] ; 
            var ch2value = eachvalue[2] ; 
            var ch3value = eachvalue[3] ; 

            results[0] = index ;
            results[1] = ch0value ;
            results[2] = ch1value ;
            results[3] = ch2value ;
            results[4] = ch3value ;

            console.log(results);

            fs.appendFile(file,results+'\r\n',function(err){
                if(err)
                    console.log(err);
            });
        });

};
```

Comment: Modify this: `eachvalue = arrayvalue.split(';');` to get sub-array of json

Comment: You first need to get rows, then you can get columns. Anyway, check [this](https://gist.github.com/iwek/7154578)

Comment: @Justinas shoud i delete this line ?

Comment: you might want to check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/elsheikh21/0c559c6e2fcd8b8981ad1f2a48b49d6e)

Comment: It seems to me you are missing headers for your data file. Each line above appears to be data lines. Add a first line like: line,val1,val2,val3,val4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function processFiles(files) {
    var file = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var output = document.getElementById("fileOutput");
        var texto = e.target.result;
        csvJSON(texto);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
function csvJSON(csv) {
    var lines = csv.split("\n");
    var result = [];
    var headers;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        headers = lines[i].split("\n");
    }
    var cont = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

        var obj = {};
        var currentline = lines[i].split("\n");
        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            obj[cont] = currentline[j];
        }
        cont++;
        result.push(obj);
    }

    return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}
```

Comment: At least add a little description with a link to the npm package and project website.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code. Credits go to: https://gist.github.com/iwek/7154578

NOTE: `split(",")`. If lines contains `,` snippet won't work. But thats not the case in your data, as far as I can see.

```
function csvJSON(csv){
  var lines=csv.split("\n");

  var result = [];

  var headers=lines[0].split(",");

  for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

      var obj = {};
      var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
          obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }

      result.push(obj);

  }

  //return result; //JavaScript object
  return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}
```